# How to construct any object from variadic constructor parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector

I am experimenting with making my own containers, and I am writing an Emplace method for my Vector class.

First, here are my Forward functions:

```
template<typename T>
T&& Forward(typename remove_reference<T>::Type& arg)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}

template<typename T>
T&& Forward(typename remove_reference<T>::Type&& arg)
{
    static_assert(!Internal::is_lvalue_reference<T>::Result);

    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}
```

They are basically identical to the `std` ones.

Now here is my `Emplace` method:

```
template<typename T>
template<class... ARGS>
void MyVector<T>::Emplace(ARGS&&... args)
{
    Add(Forward<ARGS>(args)...);
}
```

This gives me an error "function does not take 2 arguments", because Add isn't designed to work with variadic arguments. So instead I just do it in place:

```
template<typename T>
template<class... ARGS>
void MyVector<T>::Emplace(ARGS&&... args)
{
    if(size >= capacity)
    {
        AdaptCapacity();
    }

    data[size++] = value;
}
```

What am I supposed to put at `_data[_size++] = value;`? How can I construct any 'T' with the variadic arguments? If I pass a call of Forward to the constructor of T, it would just give me the same error as passing it to Add, because of the '...' syntax. What else can I do?

I tried looking inside std::vector and all I found was some function `_Alty_traits::construct` that doesn't seem to have any definition(a compiler intrinsic?)

Does that mean it's impossible for me to write a custom Emplace method?

Comment: Firstly, you need to use `sizeof...` to determine how many parameters, and make sure that you have enough `capacity` for that. Then, probably `(data[size++]=args)...` would work. Dunno really, never had to hack something like that up.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik actually Emplace is supposed to take those parameters and pass them to the constructor of T, to construct a single object of type T. So if I call myVec.Emplace(0, 1.0f); it should translate to data[size++] = T(0, 1.0f);

Comment: `data[size++] = T(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);` then vOv. Note: `std::vector` needs to handle non-default constructible types, which your (and this code above) code doesn't seem to handle.

Comment: @milleniumbug This is not emplacement, except maybe in C++17.

Comment: data[size++] = T(Forward<ARGS>(args)...); seems to work, thanks very much, and yes, it seems my vector can't handle classes without default constructor, I will have to tinker with that as well.

Comment: @NirFriedman See my remark about non-default constructible types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, if `date` itself was a `vector<T>` or some such, you could do:

```
date[size++] = T(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
```

However, if you are writing your own vector, then `data` basically holds some raw memory. What you need is to construct an object directly into that raw memory. To do that, you need placement new:

```
new (date + size++) T(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
```

Note that this placement new issue is orthogonal to using variadics and such; you need placement new when writing `push_back` as well.

Edit: because you did not tells us the type or content of `date`, and based on your comments here, I'm assuming you did something like this:

```
data = new T[capacity];
```

*If* this is what you did, then you *must* use the first form I gave; using the second form would be undefined because you are constructing an object over another object (and then you can never call its destructor).

However, this is not the correct way to write a vector (or any other generic container). When a vector grabs more memory, it should *only* grab more memory and not construct anything (`new T[capacity]` default constructs all the entries in the dynamic array), in that case you *must* use the second form.

Comment: It seems to work, however why must I use placement new? I already have enough memory allocated and I can just set the object at data[size++] to the newly created one?

Comment: @shortage_radeon Because, there is no object there.

Comment: Ok, but assuming I have specialized my vector with a default constructible type and have allocated the internal array, then it would work?

Comment: @shortage_radeon, that will 1) Create an object from the RHS, and then 2) Assign that object to the location defined by `data[size++]`.

Comment: Ok, so for default-constructible types, as long as I maintain the internal array bigger than the size, it will work. I just tested it in debug with a breakpoint in the constructor of a small class i made to test the vector with. I made a custom constructor that takes two parameters and it hits the breakpoint inside it, and everything carries on properly.

Comment: @shortage_radeon Real-world impls of `std::vector` don't use `new T[]`/`delete[]` directly, they separate between "raw memory allocation" (`Allocator::allocate`), "creating objects on the allocated memory" (placement new), "destroying the object" (direct destructor call), "memory deallocation" (`Allocator::deallocate`)

Comment: @shortage_radeon To tag on to millenium's comment, and come back to something you asked about, that `construct` is likely related to `allocator_traits::construct`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct. This is actually how containers construct objects. `construct` in turn basically defaults to placement new; allocators can override it if they wish but that's very, very rare.